# Integrating logic into paintComponent

Tags: java, swing

I am currently studying Swing and have hit a mental roadblock.  I know when I want to paint to a JPanel I need to call the paintComponent method.  I have read several places that logic should not be located within your paintComponent block.  If I want a timer to determine when something is painted, would I not have to call paintComponent from another method of another class and create an instance of that class that also extends JPanel within the paintComponent?

I think what I am trying to avoid is the following...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{


    super.paintComponent(g);    
    g.drawImage(blah,blah,blah);

    if(timesUP==true){
    paintSomethingElse(g);

    }
    repaint();
}
```

Instead I get the impression I should be creating a completely different method for the logic of the if statement and somehow paint from a separate method.

What am I not understanding?

Has this already been specifically answered?  I was unable to find an answer that helped me really understand how to separate the two efficiently allowing multiple graphics to be drawn on the same JPanel.

Comment: are you trying to paint some animation? Or do you want to change image every so often with a timer? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  If the logic is related to the actual painting process, there's no reason why you couldn't put it into the `paintComponent` method.

What you want to avoid is putting logic in the `paintComponent` that changes the state of the paint process, as `paintComponent` could be called for any number of reasons, many of which you don't have control over.

The `paintComponent` method should paint the current state of the component, that's all, it should not be involved in changing or updating that state (this could actually lead to an infinite repaint loop which will consume your CPU cycles)

Comment: So as long as I am not attempting to iterate through some bufferedImage array inside of the paintComponent(or the like) I should be fine to use the if statement to..let's say check a timer and then paint an oval at a random point that travels across the screen governed by a different method.

Comment: It wouldn't rely on the timer, I would rely on some kind of state or model which can provide you with the information you need to update the current state.  The model can be shared across multiple classes and with some kind of observer pattern could even provide alerts when modified, if required.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had to make a Java Swing application which had a lot of painting to do - the JPanel had to paint multiple custom components which moved around on the screen as the user interacted with them.

The `paintComponent` method is there for drawing and that should be the end of it. Conditional painting is, from my side, doable in the `paintComponent` as long as you are not waiting for conditions, setting states of other objects or anything which might on the one hand slow you down a lot and on the other send you into waiting for ever. I call the logic here reaction logic.

On the other hand, don't forget that the repainting can be triggered externally, any time you might need it. This way you can separate the logic from painting to some extent. Use listeners, create your own events, but keep action logic out of the `paintComponent`. You can easily find a way to set states before entering the painting, so that when you decide to paint, you only react to the state.

Don't forget: if you are **multi-threading**, painting might get messy if you work on half-set states of objects. **Thread carefully!**

Answer (score 0):

If the logic is very complex and may be too slow for calling from inside the `paintComponent` (all GUI of your app is stalled while this method is running), you should define a separate `update` method to prepare precomputed boolean flags, coordinates, images and other values that `paintComponent` could use to produce the final view quickly enough.

Such update method can run in a separate thread. You should call `repaint()` or (if layout may change) `invalidate()` at the end of this method. Use a separate object for all prepared values and make sure that painting thread and updating thread do not access the same instance a once.

If the logic is fast enough, I see no problem in defining it inside the `paintComponent` method. If the logic is complex but still fast enough, define it in some methods that are called from `paintComponent` directly.